# Docker systemd init at buildtime

Tags: docker, dockerfile, centos7, systemd

So I want to install and execute a program (ESET Endpoint Antivirus) in a centOS 7 Docker container. Problem is I visibly can't install it before running `/usr/sbin/init`.
This is very annoying because we can't `RUN /usr/sbin/init` in a Dockerfile while we should be able to install via rpm at buildtime. This means I need to install at runtime every time (it takes up to 2 minutes), and since I need to `--rm` my containers after each task, it is very inefficient.

If I try to run the container with the `rpm -i /eea-9.1.4.0-el7.x86_64.rpm` as the command argument, I get `Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory`.

The problematic part is here (output of `rpm -qp --scripts /eea-9.1.4.0-el7.x86_64.rpm`):

```bash
preinstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):
#!/bin/sh

# Script to be run before package is installed / upgraded

SYSTEMD_CAT="$(which systemd-cat 2>/dev/null || true)"
print_error() {
    errorstr="ESET Endpoint Antivirus error: $1"
    echo "$errorstr" 1>&2
    if [ -n "$SYSTEMD_CAT" ]; then
        printf "%s" "$errorstr" | $SYSTEMD_CAT -t "eea" -p err
    fi
}

# Check for UTF-8 support
if ! localectl list-locales | grep -i "UTF-8\|UTF8" 1>/dev/null ; then
    print_error 'UTF-8 support is not installed in the system. Please install a UTF-8 locale first. Aborting installation.'
    exit 1
fi
```

The call to `localectl list-locales` returns the aforementioned bus error.

If I run `/usr/sbin/init` first and then install via `exec` everything works fine.
I already extensively browsed the Internet and didn't find a satisfying answer/alternative, so I ask here. If you know a more efficient way to use systemd based OS in a container, It'll be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `if I try to set the locale first with localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.utf8` Just `export LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8` that's all needed to set locale.

Comment: @KamilCuk my bad the error is already `Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory` when I run the rpm command. I am convinced that it is because of systemd not being started.

Comment: A container only runs one process and it runs in an isolated filesystem; it doesn't seem like that's a good environment to run an antivirus system.  You don't seem to have included any source code here either; is this a programming question, or more of a system-administration question?

Comment: `when I run the rpm command` Is there no other output? Please post it all. Is the error coming from a post-install script? Is there one inside the rpm? Please post the output of `rpm -qp --scripts /eea-9.1.4.0-el7.x86_64.rpm`. How about, instead of installing, just unpack the precompiled program, or have it mount from host without installation?

Comment: @DavidMaze I do it the way I've been told to do it, the container is not an option (I expose volumes containing only the files to scan). It is more of a system-administration question, since it is related to docker and systemd behavior, not to my code

Comment: @KamilCuk I've posted the output in the original post. I'm not familiar with rpm and will dig your recommendation, thanks.

Comment: Great, so install without scripts. Or mock the `localectl` command with your bash script. `This means I need to install at runtime` Installing is just copying files. You can always copy files. There is nothing except files, all `rpm -i` does is unpacking and copy. You can do it yourself if you want, you do not need anything.

Answer (score 0):

Install without executing scripts.

```
rpm --no-scripts -i ...
```